# putting word counts in database

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I have a bunch of websites on a database and I want to keep track of top words used in each website and I don't want to calculate this every time. (one time estimate is good enough)

The only way I could think of how to do this was to have a model of word and count. Please let me know what is the better way of doing this?

```
class Word(models.model):
    name=
    count=
class Url(models.model):
    address=
    words_used=models.ManyToManyField(Word)
```

The problem with my model is that I would need multiple rows for different counts of the same word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add count to the through table by explicitly defining it, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

```
class Word(models.Model):
    name=


class Url(models.Model):
    address=
    words=models.ManyToManyField(Word, through='WordCount', through_fields=('word','url'))


class WordCount(models.Models):
    word=models.ForeignKey(Word)
    url=models.ForeignKey(Url)
    count=
```

Remember you'll probably want word.name and url.address to be unique, and case insensitive unique, so lowercase them before saving/when comparing :)

Comment: I think this is better. How should I set count?

Comment: If you mean what field type, I think models.PositiveIntegerField() makes the most sense!

Comment: I can't figure out how to make instances of these in Shell.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong. I made an instance of Word. Then an instance of Url without choosing any words for it. Then an instance of WordCount using that url and word and some count. Now, automatically, I can use the Url.words to get the words associated with it? but how can I get their counts?

Comment: wordcounts = WordCount.objects.filter(url__address='http://')
for word in wordcounts:
    print('{word.name} - {word.count}'.format(word=word))

or if you have an url

for word in url.words:
    print('{word.name} - {word.count}'.format(word=word))

Comment: How should I make those objects? Filtering it is easy. like in Shell